# How to count up to certain number of rows e.g. if exceeds 1,000, then select count only up to 1,000?

Tags: mysql

I know how to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with `Limit` to return total number of rows and results for pagination.

But my question is...

What if (for performance purpose) I want to show if total rows exceeds 1,000 I just want to return 1,000 (even if there are more records)?

```
SELECT Count(id) FROM table WHERE 1
```

I Google'd a lot but couldn't find this. I thought of this thinking this may improve Fulltext search speed for example.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This just sounds like the LIMIT statement, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You said you know how to use LIMIT... Or is it something else you have in mind?

Comment: If I understood it correctly the OP wants some kind of fuzzy SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS; sort of "if more than 1000 rows were found stop counting". And no, this cannot be done (with MySQL)

Comment: Well i mean... SELECT count(id) FROM table LIMIT 1000 still returns total number of rows. I want to count up to 1000 more quickly for complex queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many cases it can be faster, but you should test it:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT 1 FROM t LIMIT 1000 ) a
```

Comment: what 'a' in the last? a typo?

Comment: i guess it's not typo. what is it called? so i can look up what it is. thanks

Comment: @user706087 **a** is an alias. MySQL requires to add an alias for every subquery. It can be **a** or **foobar** or anything you want.

Comment: @user706087: Unless you're using an alias for something within the query or result set, it isn't required.

Comment: @user706087 that's not true - it's sometimes required regardless of whether or not you actually use it

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure that mysql has its own counter for the rows built in, when a record gets inputed the marker goes up a notch, what you can do is something like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE maxrows = '1'";
```

Then have one thousand rows that get the value of one in a  `maxrows` cell, value of two for another one thousand rows and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEAST(Count(id),1000) FROM table WHERE 1
```

Documentation on the LEAST function can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least